# Getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AlchemyProvider')" in EtherJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, ethers.js

I just want to get the latest block number. I followed the docs of Alchemy, but getting the error:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider(
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AlchemyProvider')
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\BlockChain\Ether JS\readBlockchain.js:5:39)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)  
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Here is my code to find the latest block :

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
require("dotenv").config();

const network = "mainnet";
const provider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider(
  network,
 process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY
);

const queryBlockchain = async () => {
  const blockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
  console.log(blockNumber);
};

queryBlockchain();
```

The code works just fine if specify the actual path of providers .

Here is the modified code:

```
const { AlchemyProvider } = require("@ethersproject/providers");
require("dotenv").config();

const network = "mainnet";

const provider = new AlchemyProvider(network, process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY);

const queryBlockchain = async () => {
  const blockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
  console.log(blockNumber);
};

queryBlockchain();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v6 it should be ethers.AlchemyProvider. See this issue on github: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/3794#issuecomment-1434049759